why is this red warning , cleared the cache , just opened the site no code but it compiles well when i add it , how to fix?
why is this red warning , cleared the cache , just opened the site no code but it compiles well when i add it , how to fix ?

It could be a bug in remix. As of 2024-09-24 a new empty file shows no warning.
If the file had a contract and you delete all the content the minimum required to show no warning are the two lines
// SPDX-License-Identifier: ISC
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


Comment with source code license
Compiler version required


thanks i solved the problem
